# jQuery toggleClass unexpected behavior [UPDATE]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

For a new webdesign I have two 50% width slider div's as a menu, and I want to add/remove/toggle the 'open' class with jQuery. On the click of one of the .menul, the #left should have added class .open, unless #right:hover and the other way around. The first time you click it works, but the second time you click there's something going wrong, but I can't seem to figure out what it is...

Here's my HTML:

```
<div id='home'>
    <div class='slide' id='left'>
        <div class='wrap'>
            <div class='text'><a class='menul' href='#sounds'>Savado <span>Sounds</span></a><br/>
            <div class='subtext'>
                <a class='menul' href='#artist'>Performing artist</a><br/>
                <a class='menul' href='#composer' id='one'>Media Composer</a><br/>
                <a class='menul' href='#producer' id='two'>Band Producer</a></div>
            </div>
            <div class='inner'></div>
            <a class='full' href='#home'></a>
        </div>
        <div class='logo' id='logol'>
            <a href='#home'><img src='//savado.nl/new/logo.png' alt='Savado' /></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='slide' id='right'>
        <div class='wrap'>
            <div class='text'><a class='menur' href='#designs'>Savado <span>Designs</span></a><br/>
                <div class='subtext'>
                    <a class='menur' href='#management'>Content Management</a><br/>
                    <a class='menur' href='#portfolio' id='one'>Design Portfolio</a><br/>
                    <a class='menur' href='#engines' id='two'>Search Engines</a></div>
            </div>
            <div class='inner'></div>
            <a class='full' href='#home'></a>
        </div>
        <div class='logo' id='logor'>
            <a href='#home'><img src='//savado.nl/new/logo.png' alt='Savado' /></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here's my jQuery: **updated**

```
$('.menul').click(function(){
    $('#left').addClass('open');
    $('#right').removeClass('open');
    $('#right').hover(function(){$('#left').toggleClass('open')});
});
$('.menur').click(function(){
    $('#right').addClass('open');
    $('#left').removeClass('open');
    $('#left').hover(function(){$('#right').toggleClass('open')});
});
```

And here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lmxgah9o/1/ **updated**

Any help would be very much appreciated!

**[UPDATE]**

I updated my jQuery and fiddle, without any result. Thanks a lot for all comments so far, but my case is still nog solved! Some solutions were close, but lost the .open when not hovering on the .slide. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: .menul and .menur has 3 click-events. #right and #left are getting everytime when ".menul" or ".menur" is clicked a new hover event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I added my answer from [**your other question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25268429/jquery-toggleclass-conflict) to this thread now
>   as well to ensure it is not getting lost as I think your other
>   question may get closed as a duplicate of this one.

---

I had another look and you will have to add another class or data attribute to differentiate between an active-and-closed menu and a active-and-open menu or this won't work.

The active "flag" is to ensure you only toggle the `.open` class on an active menu.

In addition you also need to keep unbinding the `hover` event as otherwise you are constantly re-binding the `hover`, causing the element to have multiple `hover` events bound which then will **all** execute and contradict each other.

Note that when unbinding the `hover` event using jQuery `off('hover')/unbind('hover')` doesn't work and you must unbind the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events as those are bound by jQuery when using `selector.hover(...)`

The new JavaScript code is as follows:

```
$('.menul').click(function () {    
    $('#left').addClass('active');
    $('#left').addClass('open');
    $('#right').removeClass('active');

    $('#right').off('mouseenter mouseleave').hover(function(){
        if($('#left').hasClass('active')){
            $('#left').toggleClass('open');
        }
    });
});

$('.menur').click(function () {
    $('#right').addClass('active');
    $('#right').addClass('open');
    $('#left').removeClass('active');

    $('#left').off('mouseenter mouseleave').hover(function(){
        if($('#right').hasClass('active')){
            $('#right').toggleClass('open');
        }
    });
});
```

---

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/gf2301f5/) - Using a separate indicator for an active menu

---

Answer (score 1):

Try to query the DOM less often, ideally this can be refactored even more to utilize variables with jQuery selectors. This will help keep things organized and more efficient. I'm not sure if my logic does exactly what you need but the starting point is better.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lmxgah9o/3/)

```
$('.menul').on('click', function () {
    $('#left').toggleClass('open');
    $('#right').toggleClass('open');
});

$('#right').on('mouseenter', function () {
    $('#left').toggleClass('open');
});
$('.menur').on('click', function () {
    $('#right').toggleClass('open');
    $('#left').toggleClass('open');
});

$('#left').on('mouseenter', function () {
    $('#right').toggleClass('open');
});
```

Comment: isn't on() an event delegate?

Comment: no. [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) has multiple syntax, this one binds directly. `$(parent).on("event","selector",handler)` does the delegation...

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that you are binding multiple click events to each of your elements. When you do this, the order in which these click events are triggered is **never guaranteed**. As everyone has suggested, try using the `.toggleClass()` method in your scenario.

In addition, if you need to call multiple methods inside a click event, just do so like this:

```
function1() { // stuff }
function2() { // stuff }

$('.elem').click(function() {
    function1();
    function2();
});
```

It's not a good idea to bind multiple click events to the same element because browser behavior could be wildly different.

Now, let's take a look at the following block of code you provided:

```
$('.menul').click(function () {
    $('#right').hover(function () {
        $('#left').toggleClass('open')
    })
});
```

A big problem with this is that your hover event is not actually bound to the element until the click event on a `.menul` is fired. Also, the hover event will be bound multiple times if you click a `.menul` element multiple times. Instead, you should only bind the event *one time*, or if you so choose, make sure you unbind the event when appropriate before re-binding it.

Comment: >"_make sure you unbind the event when appropriate before re-binding it._"
How would that be?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code. Removed unnecessary and recursive code.

```
$('.menul').click(function(){
    $('#left').addClass('open');
    $('#right').removeClass('open');
});

$('#right').mouseover(function(){
    $('#left').removeClass('open');
});

$('.menur').click(function(){
    $('#right').addClass('open');
    $('#left').removeClass('open');
});
$('#left').mouseover(function(){
    $('#right').removeClass('open')
});
```

Check [here on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anil1095/wkg6w45z/1/)

Comment: So close! Thanks! But now, when I leave the #right menu directly (down) everything is fine, but when I hover over the #left and then leave, the .open class for #right is gone... **Does anyone know how to solve this?**

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't add an event handler inside another handler. This will keep on adding multiple handlers for the former event whenever the later event is triggered and it'll result in unexpected results.

Ideally your code should be something like

```
$('.menul').click(function () {
  $('#right').removeClass('open');
  $('#left').addClass('open');
});

$('.menur').click(function () {
  $('#left').removeClass('open');
  $('#right').addClass('open');
});

$('#left').hover(function () {
  $('#right').removeClass('open');
  $(this).addClass('open');
},
function () {
  $(this).removeClass('open')
});

$('.#right').hover(function () {
  $('#left').removeClass('open');
  $(this).addClass('open');
},
function () {
  $(this).removeClass('open')
});
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/Lmxgah9o/1/)

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: @SamvanDoorn actually what exactly is not working..?

Answer (score 1):

This one should work

```
$('.menul').click(function(){
    $('#left:hidden').addClass('open');
    $('#right:visible').removeClass('open');
});
$('#right').hover(function() {
    $('#left:visible').removeClass('open');                     
}) ...
```

You must do the same for #right block too... http://jsfiddle.net/ytexqtyg/

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work... But thanks for trying! Perhaps you know how to solve the problem I explained in my comment to @Anil Kumar's suggestion?