# jQuery toggleClass conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

For a new webdesign I have two 50% width slider div's as a menu, and I want to add/remove/toggle the 'open' class with jQuery. On the click of one of the .menul, the #left should have added class .open, unless #right:hover and the other way around. The first time you click it it works, but the second time you click it seems to be that the toggleClass is stuck / not updated... Does anyone know how to fix this?

Here's my HTML:

```
<div id='home'>
    <div class='slide' id='left'>
        <div class='wrap'>
            <div class='text'><a class='menul' href='#sounds'>Savado <span>Sounds</span></a><br/>
            <div class='subtext'>
                <a class='menul' href='#artist'>Performing artist</a><br/>
                <a class='menul' href='#composer' id='one'>Media Composer</a><br/>
                <a class='menul' href='#producer' id='two'>Band Producer</a></div>
            </div>
            <div class='inner'></div>
            <a class='full' href='#home'></a>
        </div>
        <div class='logo' id='logol'>
            <a href='#home'><img src='//savado.nl/new/logo.png' alt='Savado' /></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='slide' id='right'>
        <div class='wrap'>
            <div class='text'><a class='menur' href='#designs'>Savado <span>Designs</span></a><br/>
                <div class='subtext'>
                    <a class='menur' href='#management'>Content Management</a><br/>
                    <a class='menur' href='#portfolio' id='one'>Design Portfolio</a><br/>
                    <a class='menur' href='#engines' id='two'>Search Engines</a></div>
            </div>
            <div class='inner'></div>
            <a class='full' href='#home'></a>
        </div>
        <div class='logo' id='logor'>
            <a href='#home'><img src='//savado.nl/new/logo.png' alt='Savado' /></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here's my jQuery:

```
$('.menul').click(function(){
    $('#left').addClass('open');
    $('#right').removeClass('open');
    $('#right').hover(function(){$('#left').toggleClass('open')});
});
$('.menur').click(function(){
    $('#right').addClass('open');
    $('#left').removeClass('open');
    $('#left').hover(function(){$('#right').toggleClass('open')});
});
```

And here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ytexqtyg/2/

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Cant reproduce it in chrome, what is your browser

Comment: @AshishBalchandani Chrome 36

Comment: @SamvanDoorn: Is [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/7howf7td/) what you need?

Comment: @FrançoisWahl Unfortunately, that didn't do the trick either, because now the .open for #left stays in place on #right:hover...

Comment: @SamvanDoorn:  Could you please explain what it is you want to happen exactly. Ignore your named identifiers and classes `#right`, `'open` , etc.. but if possible, explain simply what is is you expect to happen. i.e: `When I hover over the left menu I want X to happen, until I click the left menu, then I want Y to happen until I click it again.` - Or similar :) - Basically go over the expected business logic/behaviour. I think that might make it easier to understand (for me and others) how to fix then :)

Comment: @FrançoisWahl I want the active slide to be open unless you hover the other/not-active slide. i.e: You click Sounds, left is open. You hover right, left closed, untill you no longer hover. If you don't hover any side (but the white space below), the left is still open, because Sounds is active (So far this works). Then you click Designs, the right slide is open (unless hover on left), but when you don't hover any side, the left is still open...

Comment: @SamvanDoorn: I understand now. Looking at this again I have a feeling it is your CSS you have `.slide:hover .subtext, .open .subtext {...}` that interferes with the expected behaviour but I'm not 100% certain :(

Comment: @FrançoisWahl I think the problem is that the open class on the left cannot be removed on click right, because it's not there on that moment, because the hover on right toggles it to be off...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had another look and you will have to add another class or data attribute to differentiate between an active-and-closed menu and a active-and-open menu or this won't work.

The active "flag" is to ensure you only toggle the `.open` class on an active menu.

In addition you also need to keep unbinding the `hover` event as otherwise you are constantly re-binding the `hover`, causing the element to have multiple `hover` events bound which then will **all** execute and contradict each other.

Note that when unbinding the `hover` event using jQuery `off('hover')/unbind('hover')` doesn't work and you must unbind the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events as those are bound by jQuery when using `selector.hover(...)`

The new JavaScript code is as follows:

```
$('.menul').click(function () {    
    $('#left').addClass('active');
    $('#left').addClass('open');
    $('#right').removeClass('active');

    $('#right').off('mouseenter mouseleave').hover(function(){
        if($('#left').hasClass('active')){
            $('#left').toggleClass('open');
        }
    });
});

$('.menur').click(function () {
    $('#right').addClass('active');
    $('#right').addClass('open');
    $('#left').removeClass('active');

    $('#left').off('mouseenter mouseleave').hover(function(){
        if($('#right').hasClass('active')){
            $('#right').toggleClass('open');
        }
    });
});
```

---

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/gf2301f5/) - Using a separate indicator for an active menu

---

Comment: @SamvanDoorn: I updated the answer and it seems to work now...I hope :) - A added this answer also to your last question as I think this question is a duplicate of your last and might get closed as such. - Just in case :)